# MySQL - freezing when I try INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql

Note, I am a relative newbie and ran into a problem using a book to learn PHP and Mysql.

In a database named "zips" with one existing table named "zip_codes," I added a table named stores successfully in mysql using this code

```
 CREATE TABLE stores ( 
    store_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    address1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    address2 VARCHAR(100) default NULL, 
    zip_code INT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL, 
    phone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (store_id), 
    KEY (zip_code) 
    );
```

Afterwards, I inserted the 15 or so lines of data below into the table, but during the numerous times that I tried it just seemed to freeze things. For example, instead of giving me the usual rows affected output, the command line just shows an `'>` and I am unable to enter anymore SQL, can't even quit.

So I manually shut down the command line and opened it up again and tried the same thing with the same result. For the sake of variation, I also tried to just enter one row of data (intead of the 15) but got the same result.

Does anyone know what's happening?

```
INSERT INTO stores (name, address1, address2, zip_code, phone) VALUES 
(‘Ray''s Shop', ‘49 Main Street', NULL, ‘63939', ‘(123) 456-7890'), 
(‘Little Lulu''s', ‘12904 Rockville Pike', ‘#310', ‘10580', ‘(123) 654- 7890'), 
(‘The Store Store', ‘8200 Leesburg Pike', NULL, ‘02461', ‘(123) 456- 8989'), 
(‘Smart Shop', ‘9 Commercial Way', NULL, ‘02141', ‘(123) 555-7890'), 
(‘Megastore', ‘34 Suburban View', NULL, ‘31066', ‘(555) 456-7890'), 
(‘Chain Chain Chain', ‘8th & Eastwood', NULL, ‘80726', ‘(123) 808-7890'), 
(‘Kiosk', ‘St. Charles Towncenter', ‘3890 Crain Highway', ‘63384', ‘(123) 888-4444'), 
(‘Another Place', ‘1600 Pennsylvania Avenue', NULL, ‘05491', ‘(111) 456- 7890'), 
(‘Fishmonger''s Heaven', ‘Pier 9', NULL, ‘53571', ‘(123) 000-7890'), 
(‘Hoo New', ‘576b Little River Turnpike', NULL, ‘08098', ‘(123) 456-0000'), 
(‘Vamps ‘'R'' Us', ‘Our Location', ‘Atwood Mall', ‘02062', ‘(222) 456- 7890'), 
(‘Five and Dime', ‘9 Constitution Avenue', NULL, ‘73503', ‘(123) 446- 7890'), 
(‘A & P', ‘890 North Broadway', NULL, ‘85329', ‘(123) 456-2323'), 
(‘Spend Money Here', ‘1209 Columbia Pike', NULL, ‘10583', ‘(321) 456- 7890');
```

Comment: format your insert properly. Lots of quotes error here.

Comment: @Emmerman  thanks, can you give me an example of a formatting error?

Comment: escape all your values http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with your quotation marks--they don't match.  You should put strings in either single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` (same opening and closing mark).

```
INSERT INTO stores (name, address1, address2, zip_code, phone) VALUES 
("Ray's Shop", '49 Main Street', NULL, '63939', '(123) 456-7890');
```

...and so forth.

The `>` prompt on the mysql command line indicates that it's waiting for further input. In practice, I find this usually happens when I omit the ending semicolon.  However, if the interpreter thinks you're in the midst of entering a string, it will assume your semicolon is part of that string and happily wait for you to finish.

Comment: I only see single quotes around every entry. How don't they match? Can you give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: You are opening with some sort of curvy open quote character and closing with the ASCII single quote `'`.  They're different characters.

Comment: thanks. it worked. did you put double quotes "" around Ray's Shop because it had an apostrophe in it?

Comment: Yes, although the way you had it was fine too: `'Ray''s Shop'`

Comment: But so why did yours work, but the first two lines of mine not work. I don't see any other difference then?

Comment: Note the difference between `‘49 Main Street'` and `'49 Main Street'`. It's the quotation marks around your string literals that are the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function like below example

```
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO product_description (language_id,name) VALUES ( '1','%s') ",mysql_real_escape_string($product_name));   
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried you code in phpmyadmin, it was some mistake there. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `stores` (`store_id`, `name`, `address1`, `address2`, `zip_code`, `phone`) 
VALUES (NULL, "Ray's Shop", '49 Main Street', NULL, '63939', '(123) 456-7890');
```

Comment: I got an error when I tried your example. Do you see any problem? You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NSERT INTO `stores` (`store_id`, `name`, `address1`, `address2`, `zip_code`, `ph' at line 1

Comment: That's strange, it's works for me. Try use code above with _"Ray's Shop"_.

Comment: It shouldn't work.  The backquote character is used only to delimit table and field names, and is rarely necessary.  Literal strings should be delimited with single `'` or double `"` quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but somehow it works in my localhost. I'm using mysql5.1.53 which comes with WampServer Version 2.1.